# Excel - Notification if Opened

Tags: excel, security

I am looking for advice on managing an issue. We need to silently track who is opening documents and how frequently. Though we could password-protect these documents, we need to know who is trying to open them.

I wrote some code to record usernames of who is opening the document, but there are no universally trusted locations to put the spreadsheet so the macros will be enabled.

It would be great to receive an email that includes the username when the document is opened, though I'm not sure if this is feasible.

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use macros because they can be bypassed. Instead, you should rely on OS level [auditing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system#Security). Assuming a Windows platform, you should take a look at the various Auditing Policies that are available. Here are a couple that might be worthwhile to track:

- [Audit Detailed File Share](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee215206.aspx) -  The Detailed File Share setting logs an event every time a file or folder is accessed.
- [Audit File System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772661.aspx) - If success auditing is enabled, an audit entry is generated each time any account successfully accesses a file system object that has a matching SACL.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Are these standard settings to enable or require additional software? I'm researching both options, but the links do not provide information regarding where/how these are managed (particularly for a single document rather than universal auditing).

Comment: You can't use Auditing to just monitor a single file, but you can filter the events generated to focus on what you care about. Auditing can be configured through the "Local Security Policy" in the "Administrative Tools" control panel.